# Error LNK2019 when compiling Qt for a pre-existing MFC application

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2008, mfc

I've recently developed a QT application(NewSPOISGUI) which was to serve as a new front end to a legacy MFC application at work. This application compiles and runs perfectly when standalone. I'm using QT 4.8.2 with VS2008 SP1 and the add-in.

Currently, I'm trying to test the functionality and trying to make the Qt GUI appear instead the of the old MFC application GUI. As a test I included the header file(newspoisgui.h) from the Qt application in the MFC application within VS2008. Unfortunately, despite adding the same paths and libraries as the Qt application(NewSPOISGUI), I keep encountering :

```
qtmaind.lib(qtmain_win.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced      in function _WinMain@16
Debug/SPOIS.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

None of the solutions I could find online could be applied as they weren't for using Qt in VS2008. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.